# HubSpot data is not showing in Scribe Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, hubspot, scribe-workbench

I added some new fields to an existing list in Hubspot. These fields do have data when I look at the list. In Scribe Online, I have refreshed the metadata for Hubspot, and I see the fields, but they don't have data for the same records I checked in Hubspot. I have tried cloning the lists to a new list and referring to that list id in the scribe query block filter id, but still no data. How do I diagnose and fix?
Thanks.